# JSON is returning strange characters in Android

Tags: android, json, special-characters

I implemented an app that gets data from a JSON. JSON is returning me characters:

ÂÃ©...

How I can get that return JSON:

áéíóú

instead of

ÂÃ©

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject json) {

    nombresLista = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    if (json != null){

        try {
            JSONArray sitios = json.getJSONArray("sites");

            for (int i = 0; i < sitios.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObj = sitios.getJSONObject(i);

                String nombre = jsonObj.getString("name");

                HashMap<String, String> lista = new HashMap<String, String>();

                lista.put("name", nombre);
                nombresLista.add(lista);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nombresLista.size(); i++) {

        String nombre = nombresLista.get(i).get("name");
        Log.e("", "nombre = " + nombre);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you receiving that JSON from? Your code looks fine.

Comment: Postman for Chrome also returns the same characters.

Comment: Then the problem is the sender, the sender needs to encode their characters (utf-8) properly.

Comment: @RuiSantos is correct. sender have to properly encode data.